# How do I add TypeScript to my existing Vite (React) application?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I have an existing react app which I created using Vite. I used the react template in Vite-

```
yarn create vite my-react-app --template react
```

As the project progressed, it seemed a good idea to include TypeScript for stricter type checking.
I had earlier included TypeScript in one of my existing projects using create-react-app with the help of this clear [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript). I tried incorporating the same in my Vite app. I executed the following code in my terminal -

```
yarn add typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
```

I renamed my .jsx files to .tsx and my vite.config.js to vite.config.ts and restarted my vite server.

But to my utter dismay, the app stopped working.
I couldn't find any documentation in the [vite docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/) for adding TypeScript to an *existing* app. I also searched in the Vite Github community, but couldn't find anything relatable there.
I couldn't find anything related to this on the web too. Most of the stuff is on CRA and Typescript.

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "the app stopped working" -- how exactly? Could you share a [mcve]? Thanks.

Comment: I had since installed a new project for Typescript as I couldn't find any solution to this. So I tried reproducing the error again. The default page at http://localhost:3000 came up as a blank screen and I saw the error "Failed to load resources... with error code of 404" in the DevTools comments section. On proper inspection, I found that although I had renamed all .jsx extensions to .tsx, I missed changing the script tag's src attribute from main.jsx to main.tsx. `<script type="module" src="/src/main.tsx">` Changing it, the page elements were restored and the error was dismissed.

Answer (score 10):

I asked the question in various other forums as well. I arrived at the correct answer a few days back and would like to share it here.

Firstly, install TypeScript and types for react and react-dom,

```
npm install -D typescript @types/react @types/react-dom
```

Next, rename the `vite.config.js` file to `vite.config.ts.`

Thirdly, configure your tsconfig.json as follows,

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

,and a tsconfig.node.json,

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "include": ["vite.config.ts"]
}
```

Next, create a file named `vite-env.d.ts` inside your `src/` folder and copy and paste the following (with the three slashes at the beginning):

```
/// <reference types="vite/client" />
```

This creates a type file for the vite client.

Lastly, in your index.html, change the name of your index.jsx to index.tsx as,

```
<script type="module" src="/src/index.tsx"></script>
```

TypeScript should now work on your Vite React project.

Click on this [link](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/6799#discussioncomment-4557486) for the Q&A in Vite's GitHub

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add typescript and `tsconfig.json` file

and

```
npm install -D typescript
```

```js
        {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true
  }
}
```

Vite support ts by default

Comment: Can you add a little more detail about the steps after this?

Will it start typechecking after you rename your .jsx files to .tsx? (For context, I'm starting with https://glitch.com/~glitch-hello-react, which uses vite as default, but doesn't come with typechecking)

Comment: Looks like Vite doesn't support typechecking: https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#typescript and they recommend using `tsc --noEmit` in the build script. How do you set that up?

Comment: These two simple steps were enough for me. (I'm using Vue, but it was the same. The only thing I had to do was change `<script>` to `<script lang="ts"` then progressively rename my .js files .ts

Answer (score 0):

Also a tip: anything related with typescript installs should be put into devDependencies. Install all packages with `-D` flag. After all - all the ts and tsx files get compiled into .js

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what NetYogi said before, it's also important to mention that `main.jsx` must be renamed to `main.tsx` as well.

Full description with details of the 6 involved steps are in the comment I posted in Vite repo

https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/6799#discussioncomment-5393727